# How to send the message from popup.html to content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making an extension and want to pass the message from the **popup.html** to **content.js** but the following code alert **undefined**. Please give me a simple script that send message from **popup.html** to **content.js** and vice versa, further i will handle it. I want to access the DOM through this extension for modifying and designing the website layouts.

**Manifest**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Extension",
  "description": "Description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
   "scripts": ["background.js"],
   "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }],
  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icons/icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions":["tabs"]
}
```

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

document.getElementById('button').onclick=function(){

    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });
    });

}

});
```

**Content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");

        if (request.greeting == "hello")
            sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
});
```

Comment: Your code is working for me. Have you reloaded your extension here `chrome://extensions/` ?

Comment: what it returns in alert ?

Comment: It alerts object and `alert(response.farewell);` alerts goodbye.

Comment: Trust me its not working here

Comment: Please past the same code in the answer

Comment: I did it and still not working

Comment: Let me share my code in my answer.

Comment: Yes please thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this simple code.

> manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "description": "Test Extension",

  "permissions": [ "tabs" ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts" : [{
        "matches" :  ["*://*/*"],
        "js" : ["content.js"]
    }]
}
```

> popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="data"></div>
  <input type="text" id="text"></input>
  <button id="set">Set</button>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



>
```

> popup.js

```
document.getElementById("set").onclick = function() {

  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
            alert(response.farewell);
        });
    });
}
```

> content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");

        if (request.greeting == "hello")
            sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
});
```

> alert

[image]

Comment: this gives me the error "Receiving end does not exist."

Comment: Perhaps you did not reload the page. See this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/q/56056053/1225070