# My Extensions Google Chrome Does not Work?

Tags: javascript, html

I create a simple code to extract URL from  a website
but it's not working when I click on icon extensions

My js code

```js
var el = document.getElementById('myPopup');
el && el.addEventListener('click', yourFunction, false);
function yourFunction() {
    let x = document.querySelectorAll("a");
            let myarray = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    let nametext = x[i].textContent;
                    let cleantext = nametext.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
                    let cleanlink = x[i].href;
                    myarray.push([cleantext, cleanlink]);
            }
            function make_table() {
                    let links_table = "<table><thead><th>Name</th><th>Links</th></thead><tbody>";
                    for (let i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
                            links_table += "<tr><td>" + myarray[i][0] + "</td><td>" + myarray[i][1] + "</td></tr>";
                    }
                    let w = window.open("");
                    w.document.write(links_table);
                    console.log(w);
                    console.log(links_table);
                    
                         
            }
            make_table();
}
yourFunction();
```

My HTML code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <dev>
    <button id="myPopup">Clickme</button>
 
    </dev>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

when i click on Clickme the url not show me just empty table
can you tell me where is the Error?

video
imgur.com/a/0OS60qG

Comment: Please put your HTML and JavaScript in a single snippet (in their respective boxes) and make sure they work together so your problem can be reproduced within your question.

Comment: Also "it's not working" is not a clear or valid explanation of behavior. How is it not working? What's it doing? What's it supposed to do? Are there any error message? If so what are they?

Comment: i create a video i think it's so clear here https://imgur.com/a/0OS60qG

Comment: i add js code into the console.log  it's working but Extensions do not work

Answer (score 1):

The error happens since the popup script does not have access to the list of "a" tags. When you ran it on the browser console it works cause you are manipulating the page content, meanwhile, on the popup, it only interacts with the **popup.html** page.

Content scripts should be the only scripts able to manipulate the page content, so to fix that you probably should send a message to a content script when clicking on the button, so the content script can scrap the links and send them as a response to the popup or output as you want.

This other question may help you to see how to send messages between files:

- [How to send the message from popup.html to content script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511012/how-to-send-the-message-from-popup-html-to-content-script)